# Windows Media Player pause control suddenly gone from task bar

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

Up until last week, I could hover my mouse over the Windows Media Player icon on my task bar, and after a second or two, a play/pause button appeared (and I think a skip forward and skip back button too). Now it's gone, so I need to fully open the WMP window then click the pause button within that.

How can I bring back those buttons when hovering over the task bar icon?

It should look like this (when paused, that is. When playing, there's a pause button instead of the play button):

[image: Screenshot]

The installed version of WMP is 12.0.7601.17514

Answer (score 0):

Though I did close and re-open WMP when I first noticed this problem, and the problem remained, today closing and re-opening it again seemed to fix the issue.